# can't write to socket from cmd using sock.recv on windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, synchronization

I'm trying to make basic synchronous hello world with sockets

(server is supposed to send some message as answer for any message from client).

1. I bind `localhost:5000` to socket
2. I'm trying to receive console input with `sock.recv(4096)`
3. I try to connect to socket from the console using `curl localhost:5000`, but I can't write to the console. Also, server sends message when i connect to it, but nothing more

here is the code:

```
import socket


server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(("localhost", 5000))
server_socket.listen() 

def accept_connection(server_socket):
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        print("connection from", addr)
        send_message(client_socket)

def send_message(client_socket):
    while True:
        request = client_socket.recv(4096)
        if request:
            response = "request recieved\n".encode()
            client_socket.send(response)
        else:
            break
    print("done with sending stuff")
    client_socket.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("stuff_started")
    accept_connection(server_socket)
```

server output:

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\stuff\pth>python testing.py
stuff_started
connection from ('127.0.0.1', 53053)
```

client output:

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\stuff\pth>curl localhost:5000
request recieved
```

Comment: The output you get is  exactly what I would expect based on the code. It is unclear though what your expectation are. *"but I can't write to the console."* - whatever you mean with this. curl is not in interactive tool which expects input on the console. Try netcat for this instead. *"Also, server sends message when i connect to it, but nothing more"* - the server waits for more input or connection end. Unclear for me what would you expect the server to do instead.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you, I didn't know that about curl

Comment: Maybe you are confusing curl and netcat (nc)? curl is a tool to access HTTP servers but not for generic TCP servers. netcat is a tool to access generic TCP servers instead. Looks like you are implementing a generic TCP server, so netcat looks like the more appropriate tool here.

Comment: yes, the confusion was about that, thank your for clarifying the difference

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comments, curl is used to HTTP servers and not for generic sockets.

You can use netcat for that:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 5000
```

or just plain old Python in your favorite shell like so:

```
> py -c "import socket; s = socket.create_connection(('localhost', 5000)); s.sendall(b'data'); print(s.recv(1024))"
b'request recieved\n'
```